# Presentar días transcurridos exactos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.7

Presento un problema al mostrar los días totales al momento de digitar ejemplo 21 de febrero del 2022 tendría que salir 52 días transcurridos pero me salen los que transcurren en ese solo ese mes,ayuda con esto por favor. Necesito que me aparezcan los días total transcurridos desde el 1 de enero hasta la fecha y mes que sea digitado.

Por favor necesito de su ayuda ya se que será algo mínimo pero estoy empezando en esto y no me doy cuenta aún en donde tengo que corregir para que transcurran bien los días totales.

```
usuarios = ('kpalaciosz', '123')

usuario, clave = usuarios

intento = 0
value = True
while value:
        
usuario_input = input('Introduce el usuario: ') 
clave_input = input('Introduce la clave: ')

if usuario_input == usuario and clave_input == clave:
    while True:
 
        print('''
               BIENVENIDA °''',usuario.upper(), '''°''')
        print('''
               ***MENU DE SELECCION***''')
        
        print('Elije una de las siguientes opciones:')
        
        print('\n[a].Calcular dias \n[b].Calcular tiempo \n[x].Salir\n')
        option = input('Intoduce la opcion: ')
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 1):

Python tiene el modulo `Datetime` que nos permite trabajar con fechas de una forma muy facil. Puedes crear cualquier fecha y despues trabajar con ellas como si fueran objetos. Por ejemplo la fecha del primero de enero se crea asi: `datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1)` los valores son todos enteros (año, mes y dia)

Ahora haces lo mismo con la fecha que el usuario introduzca y le resta la fecha del mes de enero:

```
import datetime

dia = int(input('Introduce el dia: '))
mes = int(input('Introduce el mes: '))
año = int(input('Introduce el año: '))   
         
fecha_inicial= datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)
fecha_introducida= datetime.date(año, mes, dia)

result= fecha_introducida - fecha_inicial

print(f'Dias transcurridos {result.days} aproximadamente')

# Dias transcurridos 51 aproximadamente
```

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa sin usar `datetime`

```
dias_mes = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
def dia_del_año(ano, mes, dia):
    dias = sum(dias_mes[0:mes - 1]) + dia
    if mes > 2 or (mes == 2 and dia > 28):
        if ((ano % 400 == 0) or ((ano % 4 == 0) and (ano % 100 != 0))):
            dias += 1
    return dias
```

Tenemos ua lista con los días por mes para un año normal. Si tenemos una fecha como 10/10/2022, primero sumamos todos los meses previos a Octubre con `sum(dias_mes[0:mes - 1])` y luego agregamos el día del mes recibido.

Sólo nos queda agregar un día más cuando se trata de un año bisiesto y la fecha es posterior al 28/Febrero.

#### Demo

```
dias_mes = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
def dia_del_año(ano, mes, dia):
    dias = sum(dias_mes[0:mes - 1]) + dia
    if mes > 2 or (mes == 2 and dia > 28):
        if ((ano % 400 == 0) or ((ano % 4 == 0) and (ano % 100 != 0))):
            dias += 1
    return dias


print("28/2/2022", dia_del_año(2022, 2, 28))
print("1/3/2022", dia_del_año(2022, 3, 1))

print("28/2/2020", dia_del_año(2020, 2, 28))
print("1/3/2020", dia_del_año(2020, 3, 1))
```

produce:

```
28/2/2022 59
1/3/2022 60
28/2/2020 59
1/3/2020 61

Process finished with exit code 0
```